# Error showing in while using create method inside run()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer

I was trying to make a mediaplayer application for that i created a customized class and its constructor and i am also using thread concept here. But i can't use `MediaPlayer.create()` inside this method how do i do that please some one help me to fix this...

**code**

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;

public class CustomPlayerActivity implements Runnable{

int song_id;
long time;
int button_id;
MediaPlayer myStereo;

public CustomPlayerActivity(int s_id, long Time, int b_id){

song_id = s_id;
time = Time;
button_id = b_id;

}
public void run(){
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + time;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
 myStereo = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chuva);
            myStereo.setLooping(true);
            myStereo.start();
            myStereo.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            myStereo.setLooping(true);
                            myStereo.start();
                        }
                    });
                    }
                    }

                    }
```

Comment: post th stack trace. try this  `myStereo = MediaPlayer.create(CustomPlayerActivity.this, R.raw.chuva)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaPlayer.create()` takes a `Context` as its first argument.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri, android.view.SurfaceHolder)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder%29)

You are passing it an this instance of `CustomPlayerActivity`, which is why it doesn't work.

To fix, you should pass it an instance of `Context`, for example, a reference to the activity you are calling it from. You could pass it in your constructor and then use it in `.create()`.

As a side note, I notice `CustomPlayerActivity` does not extend `Activity`...I'm not sure of your architecture but this could be part of the problem.

Comment: I know. MediaPlayer.create() *requires* a context as first argument. You are not passing a context.

Comment: am sorry about the name of the class

Comment: @KenWolf yes you are right. needs a activity context. i missed it he is implementing Runnable.